# Cannot browse to dev vhost by hostname, IP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, osx-lion, vhosts

I've got me a new macbook pro last month and i decided to set up my MySQL / Apache / PHP stack manually. I followed several online guides and solved some problems, eventually i got it to work and even managed to set up vhosts (dev.local) and phpmyadmin.

Now i got an issue i don't even know how to approach - i'm trying to browse to dev.local (the server set on my macbook) from my older PC or from my Android device and i can't...

- when i try to browse to dev.local i get "error: not found"
- when i try to browse to the mac lan ip address at 192.168.1.x i do get served but from the wrong place - i'm getting the document from /Library/Webserver/Documents/ instead of the folder i'm wanting to get (/Users/Username/Sites/)

i'm guessing it's something to do with the apache or vhost configuration

Comment: I am not near my Mac right now, but I remember something about that you have to add your username with a tilde to the URL to get your local Site: http://your.computer.address/~yourusername. Did you try that?

Comment: Why would you set it up manually?  Lion comes with Php 5.3 and Apache 2.x pre-installed.  All you have to do is install MySQL using the .dmg from dev.mysql.com and you're all good to go.

Comment: The benefit of installing your own version is that when apple release an os update or a security update your config files can be replaced without warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access your local apache server through another computer on your network you'll need to either setup a DNS server or add the domain name and ip to [the hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) of the client accessing your server.

The document you are being served is the default docroot in apache, since the server can't decide what vhost to load due to the lack of a domain name (you surfed to the ip directly) you'll get served the default docroot and not the ones in your vhosts. Check the apache configuration, the /Library/Webserver/Documents path should be in there somewhere (not in the vhosts config)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Chris! I suspect that i have more than one instances of apache runing at the same time. How can i remedy that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Web Sharing turned on in your Sharing preference pane?

[image: Turn off Web Sharing]

Image from http://kav.in/installing-a-portable-local-server-in-your-mac-using-mamp.  The screenshot is from Snow Leopard, but the interface is the same in Lion.

Comment: I had it turned off, although i started apache manually via terminal.

Comment: However, this is what eventually did the trick - all i had to do is turn the web sharing on and than iwas able to reach the dev environment via my android device by browsing to dev.home ... good enuff for me!